# How to Bind RESW String to UI

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have literally just created my first Windows Phone Runtime app, and I am moving from having experience writing Windows Phone Silverlight apps. Little did I know that there are a lot of differences to consider, one being binding resource strings to properties in the UI. I have started with a `Hub` control because simply it seems like a great template. My first step was to create a new `HubSection` and create `Header` text. Generally for good practice and saving time down the road, I always add my resource strings as I create items in the UI for translation purposes. In this, I am having trouble getting the `HubSection` Header to display my resource string.

Note, I am very new to the Windows Runtime and am currently doing tutorials in CHannel9 and Microsoft Virtual Academy.

Also note, in this template I have not changed anything, so my Page `DataContext` in XAML is still

```
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Currently what I have is as follows

```
<HubSection x:Uid="HubPage.BuiltInAppsHub">
            <HubSection.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock x:Uid="HubPage.BuiltInAppsHub.Header"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HubSection.HeaderTemplate>

        </HubSection>
```

And in my Resources.resw file my key value is `HubPage.BuiltInAppsHub.Header.Text` and my value is simply `built in apps`. So a couple questions here. One, how do I link the `TextBlock` to show this string value? Also, is there a more direct way than creating a `HeaderTemplate`, could I not just do this in the `Header` property of the `HubSection` similar to how I would have done this in the `Header` property of the `PanoramaItem` in the Silverlight version? Any information, background, suggestions, etc would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT the following displays the resw resource string when running the emulator, but not in the designer which is very difficult to see where text is located

```
<HubSection x:Uid="HubPageBuiltInAppsHub">
            <!--<HubSection.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HubSection.HeaderTemplate>-->

        </HubSection>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always use the attribute XAML element you want to display your text in. There is no need to reference that in the data template as well. What you want to do here is (also remove the dot):

```
<HubSection x:Uid="HubPageBuiltInAppsHub">
    <HubSection.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection.HeaderTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

And this key goes into your resw file:

```
HubPageBuiltInAppsHub.Header
```

There's also an MSDN article on that topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965323.aspx

Comment: For some reason I am still seeing `_.di6.TestApp.Data.SampleData...` in place of the Header?

Comment: Remove the dot. Try `HubPageBuiltInAppsHub` as Uid and `HubPageBuiltInAppsHub.Header` as key.

Comment: Well, I ran across https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6df9ca5e-57c9-43f9-9811-3f83f04a5e6a/can-hubsection-header-text-be-localized?forum=wpdevelop and decided to comment out my entire `HeaderTemplate`. When I ran the emulator I can see the Header text correctly, but nothing is displayed in the designer. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, your HeaderTemplate is practically useless. I thought you needed it for any special purposes (custom styling, etc.). The translations are not displayed at design time. However you can simply set the header attribute to some value you want to display during design time: `Header="My Design Time Header"` This will then be overridden from your RESW file during runtime.

Comment: Probably will do some custom styling, just curious as to why you cannot see the translations directly?